# Sqoop creating insert statements containing multiple records

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

we are trying to load the data from sqoop to netezza. And we are facing the following issue.

```
java.io.IOException: org.netezza.error.NzSQLException: ERROR:
```

Example Input dataset is as shown below:

1,2,3

1,3,4

sqoop command is as shown below:

```
sqoop export --table <tablename> --export-dir <path> 
--input-fields-terminated-by '\t' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' --connect
'jdbc:netezza://<host>/<db>' --driver org.netezza.Driver 
--username <username> --password <passwrd>
```

The Sqoop is creating an insert statement in the following way:

insert into (c1,c2,c3) values (1,2,3),(1,3,4).

We are able to load one record but when we try to load the data to multiple records, the error is as said above.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making **sqoop.export.records.per.statement=1** will definitely help but this will make the export process extremely slow if your export record count is very large say "5 Million".

To solve this you need add following things:

1.) A properties file **sqoop.properties**, it must contain this property **jdbc.transaction.isolation=TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED** (It avoids deadlock during exports)

also in the export command you need to specify this:

**--connection-param-file /path/to/sqoop.properties**

2.) Also **sqoop.export.records.per.statement=100**, making this will increase the speed of export.

3.) Third you have to add **--batch**, Use batch mode for underlying statement execution.

So you final export will look like this,

```
sqoop export -D sqoop.export.records.per.statement=100 --table <tablename> --export-dir <path> 
--input-fields-terminated-by '\t' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n' --connect
'jdbc:netezza://<host>/<db>' --driver org.netezza.Driver 
--username <username> --password <passwrd>
--connection-param-file /path/to/sqoop.properties
--batch
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: The advise is fully valid to common relational databases, however as Netezza do not supports multiple records per statement, it do not apply here. The -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=1 is a requirement in case that one is doing exports to Netezza.

Answer (score 1):

You can customise the number of rows that will be used in one insert statement with property "sqoop.export.records.per.statement". For example for Netezza you will need to set it to 1:

sqoop export -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=1 --connect ...

I would recommend you to also take a look on [Apache Sqoop Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920029519.do) where this and many other tips are described.