# SQOOP connection-param-file format

Tags: hadoop, parameters, connection-string, sqoop

In Sqoop for Hadoop you can use a parameters file for connection string information.

> --connection-param-file *filename*      Optional properties file that provides connection parameters

What is the format of that file?

Say for example I have:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1521/mydb
```

How should that be in a parameters file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to give your database connection string and credentials then create a file with those details and use **--options-file** in your sqoop command

create a file `database.props` with the following details:

```
import 

--connect
jdbc:mysql://localhost:5432/test_db

--username
root

--password
password
```

then your sqoop import command will look like:

```
sqoop --options-file database.props \
    --table test_table \
    --target-dir /user/test_data
```

and related to **--connection-param-file** hope [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17701396/sqoop-creating-insert-statements-containing-multiple-records) will be helpful to understand its usage

Comment: Ok.  I see now.  It's just a file that substitutes the part of the command syntax. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

It should be same as the command.

Example

import

--connect

jdbc:oracle:thin:@//myhost:1521/mydb

--username
foo

Comment: Ok.  I see now.  It's just a file that substitutes the part of the command syntax. Correct?

Comment: Yes, It is an easy way to pass these details as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample command connecting with mysql server

```
sqoop list-databases --connect jdbc:mysql://192.168.256.156/test --username root --password root
```

It will give you the list of databases available at your mysql server